# How can I set a complex json object with an optional property as optional?

Tags: jsonschema

Sorry if the question is confusing.  I'm trying to get my head around jsonschema validation.  The problem I'm trying to solve is to set a property as optional.  The property belongs to a required object that is, in turn, a property of the complex type.

e.g.

```
{ "prop1" : {
              "field1" : {"type" : "string" },
              "field2" : {"type" : "string" }
           },
  "prop2" : { "type" : "string" }
}
```

If I want to declare that prop1 is required but prop1.field1 is optional, how do I do that with jsonschema?

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to specify "required" at the same level as the "properties".

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "prop1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required" : [ "prop1" ]
}
```

This schema was generated with this online tool (plus some editing):

[JSON Schema tool](https://jsonschema.net/)

Comment: I accepted the answer but it doesn't quite answer the question, which is to allow field1 of prop1 to be optional when prop1 is required.   Is optional default, such that I should set ...required: [ 'field2' ] inside prop1?